# What happens to crosscorrelation of two noise generator if one of them were to be inverted

Tags: noise, cross-correlation

I have two noise generator u1 and u2 and their crosscorrelation is given, what will happen to this crosscorrelation if u2 or u1 were to be inverted?

Comment: Cross-correlation is just a lot of multiplying.  What happens to the result of a multiplication operation if one of the operands is inverted?

Comment: Inverted noise is basically the same as noise which isn't inverted.